# How can I modify a ReactiveVar inside of a jQuery plugin event?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a ReactiveVar that I need to read from and modify inside of an initialized jQuery plugin. Unfortunately I can't find a way to call my template's context inside of the jQuery event callbacks. This is all client side. I can't use a Session here. Here is some code:

**Setup my var**

```
Template.player.onCreated(function(){
   this.isPlaying = new ReactiveVar;
   this.isPlaying.set('false');
})
```

**Init my jQuery plugin**

```
Template.player.onRendered(function() {
    initPlayer()
});
```

**relevant portion of initPlayer():**

```
master = new TimelineMax({
    paused: true
});
master.eventCallback("onUpdate", function() {
        //Template.instance().isPlaying.set(false) //can't do this here
        //reactive variables in jquery events are out of scope?
    }
});
```

I have tried running the init function in an autotracker without any luck. I know I could use a Session here but I really want a reactive variable that will be destroyed along with the template. Any ideas of how to model this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the variable from `onRendered` to your init function. Give something like this a try:

```
Template.player.onCreated(function(){
  this.isPlaying = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.player.onRendered(function() {
  // pass the reactive variable to initPlayer
  initPlayer(this.isPlaying);
});

var initPlayer = function(isPlaying) {
  master = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

  master.eventCallback('onUpdate', function() {
    isPlaying.set(false);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of that but assumed for some reason the context of the variable would be lost if I passed it that way...yet it works like a charm. Thanks a ton.